# Uploaded file has virus how to validate it?

Tags: java, file-upload, web-applications

It happened that someone filled form and attached file with virus. Our application only checks file extension and size and nothing else is validated. Uploaded files could be checked with some antivirus or something...

What is the best solution here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using https://github.com/philvarner/clamavj. Download `ClamScan.java` and `ScanResult.java`.

and then I have somelike this this to call it (untested):

```
protected ScanResult.Status virusScanFile(File file) {
    ClamScan clamScan = new ClamScan(clamAVHost, clamAVPort, clamAVTimeout);
    ScanResult scanResult = null;
    if (clamScan.ping()) {
        try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            scanResult = clamScan.scan(inputStream);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getStackTrace());
        } 
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not scan file as ClamD did not respond to ping request!");
    }        
    ScanResult.Status scanResultStatus = null;
    if (scanResult != null) {
        scanResultStatus = scanResult.getStatus();
    }
    return scanResultStatus;
}
```

If you need to install ClamAV on windows for development purposes then this may work for you:

1. Download http://oss.netfarm.it/clamav/ which contains clamd.exe;
2. Download http://www.clamwin.com/ which is the Windows version of ClamAV and contains the virus definitions updater (freshclam.exe);
3. Install both applications as normal;
4. Copy clamd.conf to C:/Clamav and edit as follows:

   ```
   LogFile C:\Program Files (x86)\ClamWin\bin\clamd.log
   DatabaseDirectory C:\ProgramData\.clamwin\db
   ```
5. Open a cmd prompt with Administrator priviledges and 'cd' to the
   Clamav folder where you will find clamd.exe;
6. type "clamd.exe --install" (no quotes);
7. Open the Windows services and set "ClamWin Free Antivirus Scanner
   Servce" to autostart.

Otherwise just connect to a Linux install via the `clamAVHost` and `clamAVPort` parameters, the values of which you will need to define.

Comment: thanks!, I installed clamAv on Linux and now I am searching Java clients for it. ClamAv doesnt provide Java client, so I guess the only way is downloading it from github.. But how do I know that the client is written well, if its nothing official? https://github.com/philvarner/clamavj.

Comment: I also run junits and some of them doesnt pass, org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :stream: Eicar-Test-Signature FOUND
Actual   :stream: Win.Test.EICAR_NDB-1 FOUND

Comment: The EICAR test signature is used to test that virus scanners can detect a basic virus. It is a very old DOS virus that is now well known and not a threat any more. I don't think that it is a threat.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use something like Clamscan and use their command line tool to point to any file that you want or include a script in your application that does the checking.

```
clamscan OPTIONS File/Folder
```

Comment: does it support linux?

Comment: yes it does.. download it from the terminal: `sudo apt-get install clamav`

Comment: thanks, is it possible to use it with java webapp? if a user uploads file using some html form, what should happen - could I invoke clamav java api or something? What would be the best approach for checking the file, is it possible to do this check during file upload (not after) ?

Comment: I don't know the exact implementation but you should be able to setup jobs in your application that checks files for virus and return result.. or create your own local web service that does the checking and update you with result or update a database or something like that.